# Put User Input to CX

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

**First attempt: I already input a predefined data. My other code won't work when there's user input.**

```
.model small
.stack
.data
    message db 10,13,"Multiply 2 x 2 x 16 =","    ","$"
space db 10,13,"$"
.code
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax



;2 x 2 = [4]--------------- 
    mov cx,2                ;cx = 2, 1, 0
    mov bx,0                ;bx = 0, 2, 4
again1:
    add bx,2                ;bx = 4 
        loop again1
;[4] x 16 = 64---------------   
    mov cx,bx               ;cx = 4, 3, 2, 1, 0                 
    mov bx,0                ;bx = 0,16,32,48,64
again2:
    add bx,16               ;bx = 64 -> ax(ah,al)
        loop again2
        mov ax,bx   

;64 = Print "6 and 4"------

    mov cx,65535            ;cx = 65,535 times (almost infinite # of loops)
    mov bl,0                ;bl =    0,         1,      2,      3,      4,      5, 6
                            ;al = 64(-10),54(-10),44(-10),34(-10),24(-10),14(-10), 4
again3: 
    sub al,10
    cmp al,10               ;al(4) is less than 10
    jl next                 ;go to "NEXT"
        inc bl
            loop again3

next:                       ;NEXT
    mov ah,09
    lea dx,message
    int 21h

    add al,30h              ;al = 4 + 30 = "34" when printed is equals to "4"
    mov cl,al

    add bl,31h              ;bl =  6 + 30 = "36" when printed is equals to "6"
    mov dl,bl               ;print 6
    mov ah,02
    int 21h

    mov dl,cl               ;print 4
    mov ah,02
    int 21h

    mov ah,09
    lea dx,space
    int 21h

        ;2x2x16 =64 

    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h
end
```

**Here is the one with the user input:**

```
.model small
.stack
.data
    message db 10,13,"The Answer is ...","  ","$"
    space db 10,13,"$"
.code
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax


    mov ah,01       ;user input 1 -> al -> cl******
    int 21h
    mov cl,al

;? x ? = [?]--------------- 
    mov cx,?                ;cx = ?, 0
    mov bx,0                ;bx = 0, ?[+bx]

        mov ah,01       ;user input 2 -> al -> bl******
        int 21h
        mov bl,al
again1:
    add bx,?                ;bx = last count of bx 
        loop again1
;[?] x ? = ??---------------    
    mov cx,bx               ;cx = ?, 0                  
    mov bx,0                ;bx = 0, ?[+bx]

    mov ah,01       ;user input 3 -> al -> bl******
    int 21h
    mov cl,al
again2:
    add bx,?                ;bx = TOTAL# -> ax(ah,al)
    loop again2
     mov ax,bx  

;TOTAL# = Print "#1stDigit and #2ndDigit"------2x2x5=20

    mov cx,65535            ;cx = 65,535 times (almost infinite # of loops)
    mov bl,0                ;bl =       0,         1,     2,     3,     4,     5, 6     <-COUNT#
                        ;al = TOTAL#(-10),#(-10),#(-10),#(-10),#(-10),#(-10), ......FINAL#
again3: 
    sub al,10
    cmp al,10               ;al(FINAL#) is less than 10
    jl next                 ;go to "NEXT"
        inc bl
            loop again3

next:                       ;NEXT
    mov ah,09
    lea dx,message
    int 21h

    add al,30h              ;al = FINAL# + 30 =  when printed is equals to "FINAL# real value"
    mov cl,al

    add bl,31h              ;bl = COUNT# + 30 = when printed is equals to "COUNT# real value"
    mov dl,bl               ;print 1st digit
    mov ah,02
    int 21h

    mov dl,cl               ;print 2nd digit
    mov ah,02
    int 21h

    mov ah,09
    lea dx,space
    int 21h

        ;2x2x16 =64 

    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h
end
```

**It just gives me the wrong answer :/ i'm very new to TASM and it is killing me**

Basically, I do not know how to put the USER INPUT in `cx`. I just need to use `mov,ah 01h` which means the user can input only 1 digit.

PLUS, I got one more problem where if the FINAL ANSWER is a 3 digit #.

Example, `2 x 2 x 16 = 64` (safe, 2 digit only)

But with `5 x 3 x 9 = 135` (When I run the program, gives me only 5)
I don't get the logic for 3 digit answer.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> mov ah,01       ;user input 1 -> al -> cl******
> int 21h
> mov cl,al
> ```

Since the input function gave you a **character** you still need to convert it to a usable **number** by subtracting 48.
You also need to put a zero in the `CH` register because you'll use the whole of `CX` as a counter.

```
mov ah,01       ;user input 1 -> al -> cl******
int 21h
sub al,48
mov cl,al
mov ch,0
```

---

About the logic for a 3-digit answer:

You should replace the *again3* construct with a succession of 2 such constructs. The first will repeatedly subtract **100**, and the second will repeatedly subtract **10**. In between you save the results to distinct registers or variables.

Comment: ah thank you very much but.. theres something wrong after I take the input because its not giving me the right answer :/ i dont understand whats wrong

Comment: let me check again xD